# Mkmapview - Putting an annotation on every grocery store within a specific region - SWIFT

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, swift4

I want to put an annotation on every grocery store within a specific area. I already have my mkmapview working and tracking my current location.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This could help you to understand how MapKit works: https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/

Comment: You can use `MKLocalSearchRequest`. Google it :-)

Comment: @SanjayJoshi Thanks! Unfortunately, I have looked into this before and it just displays places which have the string target (as used in the example) in them. An example of what I am trying to do is, for instance, when you go to the maps app on iPhone and type in “groceries”, it will come up with grocery stores, not places that have the word “grocery” in it. Thanks!

Comment: @SanjayJoshi I got it! You were right, sorry!

Comment: You are most welcome @NikolasIoannou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try, unfortunately I'm not in situation to test it right now, but this piece of code should serve your requirement:

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Groceries"
request.region = mapView.region

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start(completionHandler: {(response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error occured in search: 
            \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else if response!.mapItems.count == 0 {
            print("No matches found")
        } else {
            print("Matches found")

            for item in response!.mapItems {
                print("Name = \(item.name)")
                print("Phone = \(item.phoneNumber)")
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I did. It gave me a list of of companies around my current location whose names has grocery in them. But not our local QFC. Thanks though.